# Compile error: method or data member not found, need to use control name as variable

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this following code

```
formName = "'" & Me.Name & "'"
Dim rss As DAO.Recordset
Set rss = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM CheckBoxT WHERE [Form Name] = " & formName)
If Not (rss.EOF And rss.BOF) Then
    rss.MoveFirst
    Do Until rss.EOF = True
        Me.rss![Checkbox Name] = True
        rss.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
rss.Close
Set rss = Nothing
```

I get error in this line `Me.rss![Checkbox Name] = True` on rss. What I am trying to do here is that, `Me.checkbox110 = true`  but in place of checkbox110 I want to use rss![Checkbox Name]. This give me error. What is the right way to use control name as variable.

Comment: `Me(rss![Checkbox Name]) = True`

Comment: or me.rss("Checkbox Name") = -1 and if you need update command me.Rss.update

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you try to do, but if it is an edit then:

```
If Not (rss.EOF And rss.BOF) Then
    rss.MoveFirst
    Do Until rss.EOF = True
        If rss![Checkbox Name].Value = False Then
           rss.Edit 
               rss![Checkbox Name].Value = True
           rss.Update
        End If
        rss.MoveNext
    Loop
End If
```